# Google Maps merge rectangles into one polygon and search it

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geometry

Below is my code with an array of bounds and rectangle drawings on the map representing each bounds item.

http://jsfiddle.net/XffyE/4/

Is it possible to merge multiple rectangles/bounds into one polygon? The goal is to search within the polygon that was created by merging the rectangles.

For example searching places within the merged bounds instead of each bounds individually.

```
    function createBounds() {

        var bounds = new Array();

        bounds[0] = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
            new google.maps.LatLng(25.941886953491675, -80.17411103748543),
            new google.maps.LatLng(25.947676224813897, -80.16767330177947)
        );
        bounds[1] = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
            new google.maps.LatLng(25.941886953491675, -80.16767330177947),
            new google.maps.LatLng(25.94622890698334, -80.1644544339265)
        );
        bounds[2] = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
            new google.maps.LatLng(25.927413775186118, -80.1644544339265),
            new google.maps.LatLng(25.94622890698334, -80.15962613214703)
        );
        bounds[3] = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
            new google.maps.LatLng(25.927413775186118, -80.15962613214703),
            new google.maps.LatLng(25.931755728677782, -80.15801669822054)
        );
        bounds[4] = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
            new google.maps.LatLng(25.927413775186118, -80.15801669822054),
            new google.maps.LatLng(25.933203046508336, -80.15318839644107)
        );
        bounds[5] = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
            new google.maps.LatLng(25.92886109301667, -80.15318839644107),
            new google.maps.LatLng(25.933203046508336, -80.15157896251458)
        );

        drawRectangles(bounds);   
    }

    // Draw the array of bounds as rectangles on the map
    function drawRectangles(bounds) {
      boundsRectangles = new Array(bounds.length);
      for (var i = 0; i < bounds.length; i++) {
        boundsRectangles[i] = new google.maps.Rectangle({
          bounds: bounds[i],
          fillOpacity: 0,
          strokeOpacity: 1.0,
          strokeColor: '#000000',
          strokeWeight: 1,
          map: map
        });
      }
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API check if marker exists in multiple bounds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17253929/google-maps-api-check-if-marker-exists-in-multiple-bounds)

Comment: @Dr.Molle For the public it's not really a duplicate because the questions are different. Yes the answer from the former question relates to this one but the topic deals with markers. Here I'm trying to merge bounds not check if markers exist.

Comment: your question here is how to merge multiple bounds into 1 polygon, and that's exactly what you have asked in the duplicate and what has already been answered there

Comment: @Dr.Molle no, the question wasn't how to merge bounds into 1 polygon despite checking that solution as the correct answer. In that particular project I had no reason to merge bounds.

Comment: @Dr.Molle to my knowledge you can't pass `LatLngBounds` to the paths property for Polygon. It accepts `LatLng`.

Comment: I'm afraid you  make a fool of yourself

Comment: I think you are by missing the point. Questions are indexed by titles. Anyone specifically interested in merging rectangles into a polygon may find this question helpful and not the other question that addresses a totally different issue. Yes the answer in the "duplicate" can apply here but that's a biased opinion which no one else can benefit from by closing or downvoting this question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fun question, the short answer is:

1. Find the coordinates of the vertices of all your rectangles
2. Sort those vertices either clockwise or anti-clockwise (whichever Google maps wants)
3. Feed those vertices as an array of LatLng objects in sorted order to Polygon() constructor

I'm sorry that I don't have time to go into detail about how to find the opposite corners or sort them all by angle, hopefully someone else can help you with that if this isn't enough.

Comment: Thanks! I tried that and it creates separate polygons exactly like the separate rectangles :( The difficult part is picking only the vertices along the outer rectangles to create one closed polygon. I was looking at this http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_polygon_example.html for an example but the script presets all coordinates whereas I have to create them dynamically.

Comment: Ah, in your example none of the rectangles overlapped. If they do you have that third problem where you need to find the points that define the exterior of the polygon that you want to create. In that case I would approach this differently. I would build the polygon by adding one rectangle at a time and throwing out the vertices that are inside the existing polygon at each step. This assumes you have some way of checking whether a point is in a polygon, some code for this is here: https://github.com/tparkin/Google-Maps-Point-in-Polygon. I'll update my answer to reflect this.